State updating problem between 2 functions using a mutual state
I have a React component with two functions: one that fetches data (getData) and one that sends the data (sendData). When a button is clicked, I want the following to happen: if getData has not been called before, getData should be called first, then sendData. If getData has been called before, sendData should be called directly.
Here is the structure I have built:
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
    const result = await response.json();
    setData(result);
  }

  const sendData = () => {
    console.log(data);
    // data sending operations
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (!data) {
      await getData();
    }

    sendData();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
  );
}

You can see the code in this React playground (since the snippet here doesn't support some features like fetch).
Here is the problem: sendData is called right after getData completes, and since our state (data) hasn't been updated yet, sendData can't see the current state.
Of course, the first solution that comes to mind is to have getData return the data and pass the returned data as a parameter to sendData. But if for some reason we don't want to do that, can we find another solution? I thought of using useEffect, but I don't need sendData to be called when the state is updated. I only need it to be called when I press the button.

Why wouldn't want to return a data value and use it as a parameter? There are no possible alternatives unless you use the received value.

@Odri Thanks for your comment. I'm just trying to find out if it is possible to solve this by using a mutual state.

You can do something like this -
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async (sendData) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    const result = await response.json();

    setData(result);
    if (sendData) sendData(result);
  }

  const sendData = (result = data) => {
    console.log(result);
    //data sending operations
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (!data) await getData(sendData);
    else sendData();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
  );
}

Pass sendData as a callback to getData function. If passed it will call sendData and pass latest API result else it will take from state variable.
You can also write this as -
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const getData = async (allowSendingData) => {
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/');
    const result = await response.json();

    setData(result);
    if (allowSendingData) sendData(result);
  }

  const sendData = (result = data) => {
    console.log(result);
    //data sending operations
  }

  const handleClick = async () => {
    if (!data) await getData(true);
    else sendData();
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me!</button>
  );
}

Here instead of passing callback, pass a boolean and direct call sendData based on condition.

Thank you. Yes, it makes sense to use parameters.  But I wonder if it is possible to solve this using a state, without giving a parameter to sendData.

No you can't that in functional component, you can switch to class component to achieve what you are trying to do.
